# Relational model : Company has multiple companies

Tags: sql, database, uml, diagram, relational

my problem is the following :

How should I represent in a relational model :

A HQ has at least 0 or more (0,N) companies and those depend of 1 and only 1 HQ.

Knowing that : HQ has many fields similar to companies.

- A) Should I create 2 tables ? One called HQ and another company.
- B) Should it be a recursive on the same table ?
- C) Is there another way to represent this relation ?

Comment: I would put all entities in the same table and use a parent field.  The HQ would have a parent value of NULL (or maybe 0).  Then it's a simple query to get the entire company structure.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer ! It's a good idea. But what about recurisivity ? It should ask less ressources for the database to query this table that stores HQID and companyID no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same table with a parent field works very well on its own if the HQ has *all* the same fields as the rest.  However, if there attributes of a HQ that are not shared by a company as you say, then you'll also need to have a separate table for the HQ-specific data.  So yes, 2 tables.  But take jbarker's idea as a starting point.  Then add an HQ table with a companyID foreign key.  An HQ record will have the companyID of the company that is a HQ, which as he says will have a value of NULL for the parent.

As for your question about recursivity, you'll have recursive relationships or "self joins" for the company data, and not for HQ-specific data.